# Level creation of Rayman Origins type game?

Tags: level-design, levels

Does anyone know the technique they used to create their levels (using rayman origin as an example)? I'm strictly speaking of the floors and walls. Doesn't look like tiled based.  What is the workflow that would be needed for a non-tiled based game?  I am trying to implement something like this (below) but I am stuck between two ways of doing it

[image]

First: Just have art assets and get/set positions of them, similar to tiled based but the objects would be more detailed (with different positions for the x and y)-seems slightly tedious, I could save the locations to a text file and load it from there.

Second: I have seen an article which I can't find, but the game dev pretty much drew the base level (the walls, floors) and then added a bit of imagery on top of it.  So in the picture below, they would've just drew green ledges and walls, then cover them up with leaf-like assets. - I would really like to implement this option, as I could for example, draw a straight line for a hill, then cover it up with some assets, but the collision would still be the straight line

Comment: I am simply asking what technique are they using, if it's not tiled based how does it work?

Comment: See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about "what technology some particular game used". Hint, it's off topic for this site.

Comment: not asking the technology, asking what technique. I could try to explain it, but it would be very hard, so I gave rayman origin as an example

Comment: Try some screen shots of what you're talking about, tell us what research you've done. Are you attempting to implement this yourself? Even if it's "very hard" try to explain what you want, you're far more likely to get the answer you want, and you may even discover the answer yourself in the process. Also, in this case technology is the same as technique.

Comment: The level is probably either all static meshes (models) or a combination of models and BSP geometry made in a level editor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just 2D stuff done with parallax and depth of focus ala Braid and Aquaria.

Comment: They do the animations this way http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_QhZYTukac with their UbiArt engine(that was meant to go public sometime, but dont know if this still their plan for it). The levels shouldn't be too different.

Comment: Take a look at Braid it has an editor you can download an try out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the article linked to below, it might be what you're looking for...

http://javilop.com/gamedev/c-game-programming-tutorial-non-tile-based-arbitrary-positioned-entity-engine-editor-like-in-braid-or-aquaria-games/

Not only does this approach allow arbitrary x, y locations for objects, it also lets you have depth.  Depth lets you do parallax effects, plus focal depth (farther items out of focus).

This is the style used in Braid and Aquaria, both of which have an "almost" 3D look.  The game you mention may be done the same way.  Even scenes where objects are animated in a 3D way may just be animated sprites.

**edit** Looking further I'm pretty sure Rayman Origin is just a set of 2D sprites, some animated.

Comment: Beat me to it, that was exactly the article I would have linked :) Although Aquaria also uses some sort of black and white mask image of the level countours, which is automatically textured. Then other sprites are overlaid on top for detail.

Comment: It's a really sweet approach to "2D" level design - the effect is really visually powerful.

Comment: To complement Tim's answer, here's the same thing, but for Braid: http://www.davidhellman.net/blog/archives/85 ; And the thing I mentioned about Aquaria's map masks can be seen here: http://aquariawiki.ryanballantyne.name/wiki/index.php/Modify_a_map

Comment: @Tim Holt thanks I am attempting this in Unity, this is exactly what I am talking! Thanks

Comment: @DavidGouveia I want to know about the map masks! That looks fantastic

Comment: @bitbitbot I'd recommend getting Aquaria and playing around with the level editor then. I haven't used it personally, so I haven't seen exactly how they work besides what's written in the wiki. The game is [open source](http://infiniteammo.ca/blog/aquaria-source-released/). *By the way, funny that Aquaria was done by "bit blot", that's almost your username lol.*

Answer (score 9):

I can give more insights on this since I worked on it. We were indeed using a level editor similar to what's described in Tim Holt's answers: levels are built in 3D but all objects are flat, and the projection is orthographic.

But there is more than "a set of 2D sprites". The way UBIart worked at that time (I'm sure it evolved quite a lot today with the upcoming release of *Rayman Legends*) is that we had roughly two different sets of entities:

- The *friezes* were the blockout geometry, so the static collisions on the gameplay side. Level designers could edit them with a simple polygon editor to create a level's layout. Level artists could create and assign different sets of border and filling textures to give the levels their base look.
- The *actors* were either decoration or gameplay elements, using a component-based system. Most of them were either static images, or animated using a custom 2D skeletal animation tool. Level designers could place gameplay actors them anywhere in a level and play right away. Level artists could also drop images straight into the editor which would create actors for them.

The key point was that level editing was done straight in the game engine: any change in layout or look could be tested in-game straight away.

---

If you're interested, you'll find some pretty interesting articles on Gamasutra:

- [Rational Design: The Core of *Rayman Origins*](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/167214/rational_design_the_core_of_.php) by Chris McEntee
- *Rayman Origins* postmortem in [Game Developer Magazine (October 2012)](http://gdmag.com/issue/2012/October) by Christ McEntee
- [The Evolutionary Process Of Building *Rayman Origins*](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/6562/the_evolutionary_process_of_.php) by William Audureau